# SwiftUI: Force List Row to adjust height to content

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

I'm having some issues with a List that won't change the row's height. I split it off into an easy example.

This is the entire demo code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  let items = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3"]
  @State var error: [String: String] = []
  
  var body: some View {
    List {
      ForEach(self.items, id: \.self) { item in
        VStack {
          Text(item)
            .padding()
          if let e = error[item] {
            Text(e)
          }
        }
        .swipeActions(edge: .leading, allowsFullSwipe: true) {
          Button(action: {
            self.error[item] = "ERROR!"
          }) {
            Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
          }.background(Color.blue)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to show an error message below the regular item, once the user swipes the cell. Unfortunately what happens now is this:

[image: issue]

What I want it to look like is this (for this I added an element to the 'error' dictionary in the code):

[image: fix]

It seems to me like a problem many people would face, but I haven't been able to find much information about this issue. I've tried some things (for example the '.fixedSize' modifier), but nothing I have tried has worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

List caches created rows, so we need to let it known that specific row should be rebuilt from scratch. The possible solution is to use `.id` dependent on same condition as optional error text.

Tested with Xcode 13.2 / iOS 15.2

[image]

Here is modified part of code (some extra added for demo):

```
.swipeActions(edge: .leading, allowsFullSwipe: true) {
  Button(action: {
    if nil == self.error[item] {
        self.error[item] = "ERROR!"
        } else {
            self.error[item] = nil
        }
  }) {
    Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
  }.background(Color.blue)
}
.id(item + (self.error[item] ?? ""))   // << here !!
```